# How to add permissions based on flavor to Android manifest using Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-permissions

Can I somehow add/not add certain permission to manifest for certain flavors?

Lets say I have 2 flavors

```
>main
>cloud
```

I have permission REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES. I want to have it in "main" flavor, but I don't want this in "cloud" flavor. Can I do that using variables in Gradle?

I've already tried approach with setting all permissions in main manifest, and then removing it in flavor manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tool:node="remove"/>
```

But it does nothing, merged manifest is still with this permission. So I think the approach with adding it through gradle would be better, but I don't really know how to do that.

@edit

Below is my Gradle flavor dimensions and definitions:

```
   def enableCrashlyticsInDebugBuild = false
    def enableCrashlyticsInReleaseBuild = true

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
            }
            proguardFile 'proguard.cfg'
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled:"${enableCrashlyticsInReleaseBuild}"]
        }
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled:"${enableCrashlyticsInDebugBuild}"]
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "environment", "distribution"
    productFlavors {

        enterprise {
            dimension 'distribution'
        }

        store {
            dimension 'distribution'
        }

        sampleBuildType {
            dimension 'environment'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.sampleConfig
            applicationId "com.sample.sampleBuildType"
            buildConfigField "String", "DEFAULT_APP_THEME", "\"DARK\""
            buildConfigField "String", "APP_CATEGORY", "\"ENTERPRISE\""
        }
        cloud {
            dimension 'environment'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.cloudConfig
            applicationId "com.comarch.sample.Cloud"
            buildConfigField "String", "DEFAULT_APP_THEME", "\"DARK\""
            buildConfigField "String", "APP_CATEGORY", "\"ENTERPRISE\""
        }
```

Additionaly I've found some code in Gradle which I don't really understand that might be relevant:

```
    variantFilter { variant ->
        def names = variant.flavors*.name

        if (names.contains("store") && !names.contains("cloud_prod")) {
            setIgnore(true)
        }

        if (names.contains("enterprise") && names.contains("cloud_prod")) {
            setIgnore(true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `main` is not a flavor. You might consider posting your actual flavor dimensions and definitions from your Gradle build file.

Comment: I've added part of my gradle file. I want to remove certain permission from manifest file for cloud flavor and I want to leave it for "sampleBuildType". Maybe I can do this using some script in gradle?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. If I add a permission in `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and then remove it in a flavor-specific manifest, then it isn't present in the merged manifest when building that flavor.  Which is as expected, since the flavor-specific manifest has higher priority in the merge process. Have you looked at the output under `app/build/intermediates/manifest_merge_blame_file/` to see if it contains any hints about what is happening?

Comment: Yes, that should be expected output. I've added     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/> in main manifest file and added     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tool:node="remove"/> in flavor specific manifest file, but merged manifest file still has this permision. I've checked output of folder that you specified and it is indeed being merged to the manifest file and not removed.

Comment: Does the blame file say where the `uses-permission` line is taken from? Do you have any `buildType`-specific manifests (e.g. in `app/src/release` or `app/src/debug`) that include this permission? Which Android Gradle Plugin version are you using?

Comment: There is a report that does say what was merged/injected/added and from where, but there is a lot of lines to check. I don't have any build type specific manifests. I use Gradle 7.1.2

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove certain permission from manifest file for cloud flavor and I want to leave it for "sampleBuildType"

Put the `<uses-permission>` element for it in an `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the `sampleBuildType/` flavor directory. And, remove that permission from `main`, which is used for all flavors.

Comment: I want this permission in my main manifest file. I only don't want it in "cloud" flavor. Technically I could add it for all other flavors in their manifest except "cloud" which would not have this permission, but it would be a lot of unecessary files and after creating new flavor, I would have to add another manifest file and I am looking for better solution.